# You have requested package `include/foo' but the package provides `foo'

Tags: packages, compiling, warnings

I have the following files:

```
my_folder/
   include/
       mypackage.sty
   main.tex
```

The package's name is 'mypackage'. Now, in `main.tex` I do

```
\usepackage{include/mypackage}
```

using the file path rather than the package name. This works, but warns me:

> You have requested package `include/foo' but the package provides `foo'

How do I avoid this **without** placing the document class file elsewhere?

Comment: The warning is there specifically so you don't do `\usepackage{include/mypackage}` do `\usepackage{mypackage}` instead. The argument is a package _name_ not a file path, just as you don't do `\documentclass{tex/macros/latex/base/article}`

Comment: Related: [where to put .sty and .cls file for project](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34203)

Comment: If you're using MiKTeX, see [How do I set the search path for MikTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30087/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Can I include something like CWD in the search path?

Comment: @mvkorpel: The .sty and .cls files need to be exactly where they are... that is, they're particular to the document, not to my system. The only question is how to refer to them.

Comment: @einpoklum: Honestly, you *can* use it as is, since it's only a warning. If you want to silence the warning, use the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence).

Comment: Something like CWD is *already* in the search path. If you put the packages in the same directory as the document, it will work fine.

Comment: @cfr: Ok, so now I just need to add CWD/my_folder...

Comment: You really can just ignore the warning as Werner said. If you don't want to do that, you have to alter the search path. That depends on your distribution as Werner indicated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where to put .sty and .cls file for project](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34203/where-to-put-sty-and-cls-file-for-project)

Comment: @egreg: Clarified that I want to decide where to put the files...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the warning using `silence` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
%Disable all warnings issued by latex starting with "You have..."
\WarningFilter{latex}{You have requested package}
\usepackage{include/mypackage}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Another solution was proposed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31950/65072

Comment: Well, I guess that'd work, but it's a workaround rather than a solution...

Comment: Based on other answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31925/install-package-in-subfolder, you can add "include" directory to your TEXINPUTS environment variable, that's the only other solution to my knowledge. But in this case you'll have a problem -- all your documents will be compiled with this new TEXINPUTS value. I use the solution with `silence` myself, it seems more modular.

Comment: ... but the document can't really make assumptions about the environment variables.

Comment: do you have any idea how I can file this as a bug report / feature request with the LaTeX project, officially?

Comment: I was searching for bug reporting many times - Latex community doesn't seem to use public bug trackers. You should probably contact the authors of latex/miktex/whatever by email.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem recently. The issue was that I'd copied original.sty in order to have a modified version modified.sty, but I'd forgotten to change `\ProvidesPackage{original}[...]` to `\ProvidesPackage{modified}[...]` in modified.sty. As such, I got the error `You have requested package 'original', but the package provides 'modified'`. Making the above change resolved the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help where I can!