# What does "You have requested package `foo', but the package provides `foo'." mean?

Tags: packages, moderncv, warnings

I know what this message means in general ("do not add path names in package names"), and my question is not a duplicate of [You have requested package `include/foo' but the package provides `foo'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186967), where the two names differ (by the path name). In my case the package names are really identical (without path name in both cases)!

I'm working on MiKTeX 2.9, with latest updates (I refreshed FNDB). I get this with the latest `moderncv` package (version 2.0), MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\name{Foo}{Bar}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

where I get

```
You have requested package `moderncvheadi', but the package provides `moderncvheadi'.
You have requested package `moderncvbodyi', but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.
```

What does trigger this warning in this case and how can I solve it? Is it a bug in `moderncv`? The official source on https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv looks fine to me.

Comment: I get the same warning on TL 2015/Linux.

Comment: Same warning on TL 2016/Windows.

Comment: Bug is still there, tracked by https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/1 https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/7. The bug *might* be fixed on GitHub but not on CTAN (at least https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/1#issuecomment-317167797 suggests so).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

its a bug in the class, looks like a recent change in the github log, can't test here, no tex, but the package name constructed by

```
\expandafter moderncv\romannumeral
```

which doesn't do the right thing `\expandafter` does nothing there, you can ignore the warning until it's fixed.

Lines 315 to 333 of `moderncv.cls` should be changed into

```
% loads a header variant
% usage: \moderncvhead[<optional head option>]{<header variant number>}
\newcommand*{\moderncvhead}[2][]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\RequirePackage[#1]{moderncvhead\ifcase#2\or i\or ii\or iii\or iv\or v\fi}%
  }\x 
}

% loads a body variant
% usage: \moderncvbody[<optional body option>]{<body variant number>}
\newcommand*{\moderncvbody}[2][]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\RequirePackage[#1]{moderncvbody\ifcase#2\or i\or ii\or iii\or iv\or v\fi}%
  }\x 
}

% loads a footer variant
% usage: \moderncvfoot{<footer variant number>}
\newcommand*{\moderncvfoot}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\RequirePackage{moderncvfoot\ifcase#1\or i\or ii\or iii\or iv\or v\fi}%
  }\x
}
```

but it's not possible to add this code in a document, because the macros are already used by the class itself.

Comment: @egreg takes pity on a user with no tex on his computer:-) Thanks I just came back here to add that and saw you'd done it:-)

Comment: I also fixed some missing `%`. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Have you guys though confirmed it worked? I am still getting the nasty warnings after changing lines 315 to 333, but maybe it's somehow just me :(

Comment: @Xavier never trust code from an untrusted source:-)  I added a fix:-)

Comment: Shouldn't `\or i\or\ii` be `\or i\or ii` (in all three cases)?

Comment: @Xavier sorry about that: fixed now.

Comment: @David Does this work beyond `ii`? I am on a style binge, and already got to `iii`, `iv` and `v` :)

Comment: @Xavier oh didn't notice there were more, seems that 5 are needed.  look again in a minute:-)

Answer (score 5):

This bug has been fixed in the GitHub repo, but not yet (as of 2019-04-03) on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv version:2.0.0 date:2015-07-28