# moderncv won't create pdf

Tags: pdf, moderncv, warnings

while I have no errors in the Text, I get a few warnings, from which most are similar: ***LaTeX Warning: You have requested package 'moderncvheadii', but the package provides 'moderncvheadii'.***
To me this warning seems rather weird...

Here a short section:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
```

The rest of the script is simple and repetitive (section, subsection, cvline).

PS: I use TeXnicCenter if that might be useful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260446/what-does-you-have-requested-package-foo-but-the-package-provides-foo-me) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
In the end I just used \documentclass{res}, which is more simple in comparison to moderncv but works for me at the moment.