# Undefined control sequence with hypersetup in moderncv

Tags: hyperref, moderncv

The MWE below results in the error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \hypersetup
```

It's minimized from a CV that definitely compiled fine a month ago (with the warnings discussed in [What does "You have requested package `foo', but the package provides `foo'." mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260446/what-does-you-have-requested-package-foo-but-the-package-provides-foo-me)). I've tried in up-to-date setups of both MiKTeX and TeX Live. I suspect some package that was updated in the meantime is causing an incompatibility, but having a hard time tracking down which one. I'm hoping someone can identify it, so that I can revert to an older version, or suggest a workaround.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\name{John}{Doe}

\hypersetup{}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Changing the documentclass to article (and replacing the moderncv specific lines with \usepackage{hyperref}) makes it compile fine. If I include

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

I get an `Option clash for package hyperref.` error, presumably because `moderncv` is loading `hyperref`.

Comment: \hypersetup is from the hyperref package. So add \usepackage{hyperref} to your document. And no, it didn't compile previously, I checked with texlive 2018 and 2019 on overleaf. And it doesn't compile with article either, as article doesn't load hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see edit. It's quite possible I minimized incorrectly, but I'm confused by the mwe as it is.

Comment: moderncv loads hyperref with `AtEndPreamble`. So you either need to use `AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{...}}` or load hyperref with `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` to avoid the options clash.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, that seems to have fixed it, my original document had `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{...}}`, which throws a more complicated error, maybe worth asking about in a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easy workaround: simply move comand `\hypersetup` behind `\begin{document}` like this:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\name{John}{Doe}

%\hypersetup{} % <========================================= move it down

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{} % <=======================================================

\makecvtitle

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

The reason is that class `moderncv`, current version 2.0, loads `hyperref` with `AtEndPreamble`. That means that `hyperref` is called after your complete preamble. That means that your call is to early, at that moment `hyperref` is not loaded and therefore `\hypersetup` is an unknown command, resulting the error message you got.

With the moved command `\hypersetup` after `\begin{document}` package `hyperref` is already called and `\hypersetup` is a valid command ...

Comment: Although this fixes the compilation issue, this does not work as intended for me. `Package hyperref Warning: Option 'colorlinks' has already been used, setting the option has no effect`...

Comment: @Rastapopoulos please ask a new question,adding an mwe resulting in your error ...

Comment: A working solution, which I found in another answer, is the following: just before `begin{document}`, write `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}}
`, for example.

Comment: For me the work around with `AtBeginDocument` did not work but after replacing it with `AtEndPreamble` it did.