# Warning message (about Document class)

Tags: document-classes

I got the warning message... you have requested document class styles/wissdoc-kw-english. I dont know how I can solve this. My thesis.tex includes

```
\documentclass{styles/wissdoc-kw-eng}
```

Please help me! 
Best regards

Comment: Related/duplicate: [You have requested package `include/foo` but the package provides `foo`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186967/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would have helped if you had shown the warning but I can guess...

```
\documentclass{styles/wissdoc-kw-eng}
```

should be

```
\documentclass{wissdoc-kw-eng}
```

The argument is the *name* of the class not its path (and I guess that you got the warning that you requested `styles/wissdoc-kw-eng` but the class provides `wissdoc-kw-eng`)

then you should arrange that the styles directory is in your tex input path, or just put the class in the same directory as your document.

Comment: The warning message was exactly the same as you had written down. Thank you for fast help!