# Warning about document class `sigchi'

Tags: document-classes, warnings

I get the following warning:

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `sigchi', but the document class provides `chi2012'.

My tex file includes:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}
```

How can I solve this? It can't be a problem with the name (as it was the case in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288448/warning-message-about-document-class)) and I couldn't find anything about that document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class (or package) can inform LaTeX about its name (date, version, and info) via `\ProvidesClass` (or `\ProvidesPackage`). If LaTeX loads the class (or package), it compares the provided name with the file name. If they do not match LaTeX prints the warning.

Thus, `sigchi.cls` will very likely have a line starting with `\ProvidesClass{chi2012}`.

Since I do not know anything about the class(es) `sigchi`/`chi2012`, I cannot say, which one is wrong. The warning goes away, if either the name of the class or the name in `\ProvidesClass` is fixed.

Comment: If I use `\documentclass{chi2012}` I get `LaTeX Error: File `chi2012.cls' not found.`. Where can I find the document class?

Comment: Ok I found the document class and changed the name - now the warning is gone, thanks!

Comment: @Andreas -- unfortunately, your changing the name in the file doesn't help anyone else, and that's not a good thing to do anyway.  what you really should do is submit a bug report to whoever distributes the class file.  (sounds like something from the acm.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- thanks for this thint. I did some research and found the author: https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/tree/master/LaTeX
I am using an old version, seems to be fixed in the current one. Again, thanks!